# ¿Librerías necesarias para usar iframe para fullScreen en WebView?

Tags: java, android, fragment

¿Hace falta alguna librería en especial para usar el siguiente código?

Más que nada, pregunto porque me sale **toda la pantalla en blanco**, no funciona.

```
public class Boxeo extends Fragment {

    WebView appWeb;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);

        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     //    String url = "<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c\" frameBorder=\"0\" \"allowFullScreen=\"allowFullScreen\"> </iframe>";
        appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

      //watch_popup para pantalla completa un solo video.

       // String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGPvwPJZddk&list=LLtfyXpymtaCHr6pwlkeGsjw";

       // appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
     //   appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Cargamos el enlace definido
      //  appWeb.loadUrl(url);
        //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
        //appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       //     @Override
        //    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //        return false;
         //   }
       // });

       // return v;


        String video = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGPvwPJZddk&list=LLtfyXpymtaCHr6pwlkeGsjw\" frameborder=\"0\">\n" + "</iframe>\n";
        //appWeb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        appWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        appWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        appWeb.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        appWeb.setInitialScale(0);
        appWeb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        appWeb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        appWeb.loadUrl(video);


        return v;

    }
}
```

Estoy programando en *Java*. ¿Es la única solución?

Comment: Te refieres a hace que un webView este en full size en pantalla?, para eso solo con estylos, lo puedes hacer...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que la pantalla este en full size, con esta funcion, o hacerlo con estilos

1.- Función para poner en modo full la pantalla ó volver a la normalidad, solo llámala de nuevo.

```
public void fullScreen() {

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (get_current_ui_flags)
        // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
        // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
        int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
        // END_INCLUDE (get_current_ui_flags)
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (toggle_ui_flags)
        boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
                ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
        if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
           System.out.println("Turning immersive mode mode off. ");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Turning immersive mode mode on.");
        }

        // Navigation bar hiding:  Backwards compatible to ICS.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }

        // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat.
        // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments the behavior
        // of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  For the purposes of this sample
        // all three flags are being toggled together.
        // Note that there are two immersive mode UI flags, one of which is referred to as "sticky".
        // Sticky immersive mode differs in that it makes the navigation and status bars
        // semi-transparent, and the UI flag does not get cleared when the user interacts with
        // the screen.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
        //END_INCLUDE (set_ui_flags)
    }
```

2.- Con estilos, para hacer la pantalla full dependiendo la actividad

```
// archivo /res/values/styles.xml
<style name="MyWebviewBoxeo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>

// archivo /manifests/androidmanifest.xml 
<activity
        android:name=".Boxeo"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/MyDialog"/>
```

3.- metodos para introducir custom html en webview.

```
String customHtml = "<html><body>Hello, WebView</body></html>";
webView.loadData(customHtml,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

4.- si no te sale aun, puedes probar hacer esto

- Crear custom php or javascript pagina, que le envies la url del video
- retornar el iframe con la url
- solo tendrias que hacer `webView.loadUrl("http://blah.blah.com/sub.php?url=http://youtube.com/qweqwe");`

> **Nota:** por favor corrige tu pregunta para que otras personas puedan
>   entender bien tu código, y tu pregunta, ya que aparece desacomodada...